# Re-factoring java program to make fast in InputStream

Tags: java, arraylist, http-get

i have a class here it gets the calendar Events one by one. using InputStream and HttpGet. This makes the application very Slow how can i make it faster. i have following code,

```
List<ArrayList> event= getEvents(filter, urls,EmailShare)

    public List getEvents(Filter filter, String uri,List<String> emailShare){
        List eventsToday = null;
        for (String email : emailShare) {
            String uris = uri + email + "/events/";
            InputStream stream=httpGet(uris);
            BufferedReader br = 
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
            calendar = builder.build(br);
            eventsToday = (List<?>) 
                filter.filter(calendar.getComponents(Component.VEVENT));
            arrayList.addAll(eventsToday);
        }
        return arrayList;
    }
```

it is slow in *InputStream* line.

Comment: If it does an HTTP GET (as the method name implies) then it is probably slow because of network latencies. Not much you can do here, short of caching (if that is appropriate).

Comment: Other ideas: Run a couple of those GET in parallel. Investigate if the calendar API you are using allows bulk fetches for more than one emailShare.

Comment: Here i modified. yes it is getting bulk fetched with filtering

Comment: Please try closing you streams once you are done using them. This should help little.